# lambda returning bool

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda

I want to find point, which has the less Y coordinate (if more of such points, find the one with smallest X).
When writing it with lambda:

```
    std::min_element(begin, end, [](PointAndAngle& p1, PointAndAngle& p2) {
        if (p1.first->y() < p2.first->y())
            return true;
        else if (p1.first->y() > p2.first->y())
            return false;
        else 
            return p1.first->x() < p2.first->x();
    }
```

I am getting:

```
error C3499: a lambda that has been specified to have a void return type cannot return a value
```

what is the difference between:

```
    // works
    std::min_element(begin, end, [](PointAndAngle& p1, PointAndAngle& p2) {
        return p1.first->y() < p2.first->y();
    }
```

and

```
    // does not work
    std::min_element(begin, end, [](PointAndAngle& p1, PointAndAngle& p2) {
        if (p1.first->y() < p2.first->y())
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: The construct `if(expression) return true; else return false;` is fundamentally ugly. Twice as ugly if the expression is really boolean.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: True, but that is _not_ why the compiler rejects the last example.

Comment: MSalters, sure, that's why comment and not answer. This is the answer to the question "what is the difference". And this is the major difference ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The return type of lambdas can be implicitly inferred, but you need to have a single `return` statement to achieve this; that's why your "working" lambda works (return type inferred to be `bool`).

sehe's solution explicitly declares the return type, so it works fine as well.

**Update:**

The C++11 standard, §5.1.2/4 states:

> If a lambda-expression does not include a *trailing-return-type*, it is
>   as if the trailing-return-type denotes the following type:
>
> - If the compound-statement is of the form
>     `{ return expression ; }` the type of the returned expression after
>     lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion
>     (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
> - otherwise, `void`.

Your not-working lambda falls into the second category.

Comment: Interestingly, wikipedia also includes *if all locations that return a value return the same type when the return expression is passed through `decltype`.* in the set of lambdas that may omit the return type. But it looks like, according to the standard, this isn't the case.

Comment: @mackenir: Actually before digging into the standard I thought that it might be a compiler limitation as well (the original answer is phrased like that, but the edits were very soon after posting so didn't get logged). Wikipedia is definitely technically incorrect there.

Comment: BTW did you buy a copy of the C++11 standard? I can't find it for free download.

Comment: @mackenir: You can download N3242 from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/). It's not the official standard (just a working copy from February) but the differences should be really minor.

Answer (score 17):

As Mike noted, **if the lambda's body is a single return statement, then the return type is inferred from that (see 5.1.2/4)** (thanks Mike).

```
std::min_element(begin, end, [] (const PointAndAngle & p1, const PointAndAngle & p2)
  -> bool 
 {
    if (p1.first->y() < p2.first->y())
         return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Note `-> bool`.

Comment: And probably also good to take the arguments by const-reference, as the algorithm may well want to give you that.

Comment: thank you! shouldn't the `-> bool` be after () instead of [] ?

Comment: I guess it is because in the simple one-line form the cmpiler can easily deduce the return type, which he may not be able to once you introduce a conditional. Though you're right in that it is always a good idea to be explicit about the return type.

Comment: Re "I don't know why the other form works": if the lambda's body is a single return statement, then the return type is inferred from that (see C++11 5.1.2/4).

Comment: Thanks Mike for shedding light. That strikes one of my pet peeves with lambdas! Now, can we have deduced argument types?... (PS Have done the fixes mentioned by others)

Comment: Two mistakes here: `bool` is in the wrong place, as relaxxx said; and the second line has `return` instead of `if`.

Comment: @TonyK: thanks for the hint. I don't now how I copy/hasted that :)

Comment: @TonyK: I was in the process of finding out precisely what works and what not to share on IdeOne. However, Mike already explained the rule :)

Comment: @sehe `auto` parameters have since been added with [generic lambdas in C++14](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17233547).