# C++14 combining generic lambdas and variable templates

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, generic-lambda

I know about [generic lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17233547/1959975), and I know about variable templates, but, what does this do? Is it even allowed?

```cpp
template<typename T>
auto f = [](auto a, T b){ /**/ };
```

If it's allowed, can it be used as expected? That is, as `f<type>(var_a, var_b)`?

Comment: Did you find this code somewhere, or are you just making stuff up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233547/how-does-generic-lambda-work-in-c14

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @LB-- nobody said it was

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: @Simple I don't know, I thought it was a good question - I'd like some explanation too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable template must be declared `constexpr`. A lambda cannot occur in a *constant-expression*, so the initialisation is not allowed, and its `operator()` is *not* declared `constexpr`, so calling it isn't allowed.

In summary, this is ill-formed in the current C++14 draft.

Note: curiously, even though a *lambda-expression* cannot occur in a *constant-expression*, it seems that the closure type of a lambda may have a `constexpr` copy/move constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This code is legal in the current draft of C++14 now and it compiles fine with clang 3.5 trunk