# What does an C++ operator within square brackets signify?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a basic syntax question. I am trying to understand the
meaning of an operator within square brackets when used in an
assignment. E.g.

a = **[&]** (const std::string&)
    { 
        ... 
    };

a = **[=]** (const std::string& b)
    { 
        ... 
    };

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does generic lambda work in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233547/how-does-generic-lambda-work-in-c14)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They distinguish between capturing variables by reference ([&]) or by value ([=]) in closures. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda for details.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is a new feature in C++11; chances are not all compilers support it yet.