# What is the type of this self-applying factorial function?

Tags: c++, haskell, types, c++14, generic-lambda

I wrote an anonymous factorial function in C++ and compiled my code with g++4.9.2.
It works well. However, I don't know the type of my function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
using std::function;
int main()
{
    //tested at g++ 4.9.2
    //g++ -std=c++1y -o anony anony.cpp
    auto fac = [](auto self,auto n)->auto{
        if(n < 1)
            return 1;
        else 
            return n * self(self,n-1);
    };
    std::cout<<fac(fac,3)<<std::endl;//6
    return 0;
}
```

So, I wonder: what are the types of `fac` and `self`?
If I just translate the C++ code into Haskell, it won't compile because
it involves infinite types:

```
fac2 self 0 = 1
fac2 self n = n * (self self $ n-1)
```

and I have to define some recursive type  work around it:

```
data Y a = Y ((Y a)->a->a)
fac2 self 0 = 1
fac2 self n = n * ((applY self self) (n-1))
    where applY (Y f1) f2 = f1 f2
fact2 = fac2 $ Y fac2
```

So, why could g++ get exactly the right type of the `fac` function, and what type does g++ think the `fac` function is?

Comment: when you replace `auto` with some type e.g. `int` compiler should tell you that it cannot infer types and give they names. But I haven't tested it

Comment: but why could g++ infer the right type of my fac function?

Comment: `fac` in this is a generic lambda, which acts like a functor with a templated `operator()`. Note that these are new for c++14.

Comment: Here is nice answer that might be helpful [How does generic lambda work in C++14?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17233649/1387612)

Comment: As a side note, a better way to write the Haskell version is to split it into the recursive bit (namely and generically, `fix :: (a -> a) -> a` with `fix f = f (fix f)`) and the non-recursive bit. The non-recursive bit is `fact1 recur n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * recur (n-1)` and you'll notice that this (a) is not recursive, (b) has a finite and inferable type `fact1 :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)`, and (c) implements a single "step" of factorial. We then just "complete" it by combining the recursive and non-recursive bits: `fact = fix fact1`.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson you mean the Y combinator. I know that

Comment: Well, I would not call `fix` the Y combinator. It has the same effect, but there are many fixed point combinators of which `Y` and `fix` are just two examples.

Comment: This isn't so relevant, but you can write your `Y` type as a `newtype` instead of `data`, which leads to a more efficient runtime representation.

Comment: Also note that there is a pre-made version of `fix` in `Data.Function` defined as `fix f = let x = f x in x`. I *think* this is designed to save memory and/or time in certain situations, but I don't know the details.

Comment: Oh yes, I remember now: the definition in `Data.Function` makes `fix (1:)` a circularly linked list instead of an infinite list, and similarly for some other such things. It lets you tie data structures up in knots, whereas the more obvious `fix f = f (fix f)` does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression following `auto fac =` is a lambda expression, and the compiler will automatically generate a closure object from it. The type of that object is unique and known only to the compiler.

From N4296, *§5.1.2/3* **[expr.prim.lambda]**

> The type of the *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type — called the *closure type* — whose properties are described below. This class type is neither an aggregate (8.5.1) nor a literal type (3.9). The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding *lambda-expression*.

Note that because of this, even two identical lambda expressions will have distinct types. For example,

```
auto l1 = []{};
auto l2 = []{}; // l1 and l2 are of different types
```

---

Your lambda expression is a C++14 generic lambda, and will be translated by the compiler to a class that resembles the following:

```
struct __unique_name
{
    template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
    auto operator()(Arg1 self, Arg2 n) const
    { 
        // body of your lambda
    }
};
```

I cannot comment on the Haskell part, but the reason the recursive expression works in C++ is because you're simply passing a copy of the closure object instance (`fac`) in each call. The `operator()` being a template is able to deduce the type of the lambda even though it is not one you can name otherwise.

Answer (score 26):

The C++ `fac` isn't really a function, but a struct which has a member function.

```
struct aaaa // Not its real name.
{
    template<typename a, typename b>
    auto operator()(a self, b n) const
    { 
    }
};
```

The overloaded call operator hides some of the trickery that C++ performs in order to implement "lambda functions"

When you "call" `fac`, what happens is

```
fac.operator() (fac, 3);
```

so the argument to the function isn't the function itself, but an object which has it as a member.
One effect of this is that the function's type (i.e. the type of `operator()`) does not occur in the type of the `operator()` function itself.
(The type of `self` is the struct that defines the function.)

The template part isn't necessary for this to work; this is a non-generic version of the `fac` "function":

```
struct F
{
    int operator()(const F& self, int n) const
    { 
        // ...
    }
};

F fac;
fac(fac, 3);
```

If we keep the template and rename `operator()` to `applY`:

```
// The Y type
template<typename a>
struct Y
{
    // The wrapped function has type (Y<a>, a) -> a
    a applY(const Y<a>& self, a n) const
    { 
        if(n < 1)
            return 1;
        else 
            return n * self.applY(self, n-1);
    }
};

template<typename a>
a fac(a n)
{
    Y<a> y;
    return y.applY(y, n);
}
```

we see that your working Haskell program and your C++ program are very similar - the differences are mainly punctuation.

In contrast, in Haskell

```
fac2 self 0 = 1
fac2 self n = n * (self self $ n-1)
```

`self` *is* a function, and `fac2`'s type would have to be

```
X -> Int -> Int
```

for some `X`.
Since `self` is a function, and `self self $ n-1` is an Int, `self`'s type is also `X -> Int -> Int`.

But what could `X` be?
It must be the same as the type of `self` itself, i.e `X -> Int -> Int`.
But that means that the type of `self` is (substituting for `X`):

```
(X -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
```

so the type `X` must also be

```
(X -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
```

so `self`'s type must be

```
((X -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
```

and so on, ad infinitum.
That is, in Haskell the type would be infinite.

Your solution for Haskell essentially explicitly introduces the necessary indirection that C++ generates through its structure with a member function.

Answer (score 15):

As others pointed out, the lambda acts as a structure involving a template. The question then becomes: why Haskell can not type the self-application, while C++ can?

The answer lies on the difference between C++ templates and Haskell polymorphic functions. Compare these:

```
-- valid Haskell
foo :: forall a b. a -> b -> a
foo x y = x

// valid C++
template <typename a, typename b>
a foo(a x, b y) { return x; }
```

While they might look nearly equivalent, they are not really such.

When Haskell type checks the above declaration, it checks that the definition is type safe for any types `a,b`. That is, if we substitute `a,b` with any two types, the function must be well-defined.

C++ follows another approach. At template definition, it is not checked that any substitution for `a,b` will be correct. This check is *deferred* to the point of use of the template, i.e. at instantiation time. To stress the point, let's add a `+1` in our code:

```
-- INVALID Haskell
foo :: forall a b. a -> b -> a
foo x y = x+1

// valid C++
template <typename a, typename b>
a foo(a x, b y) { return x+1; }
```

The Haskell definition will not type check: there's no guarantee you can perform `x+1` when `x` is of an arbitrary type. The C++ code is fine, instead. The fact that some substitutions of `a` lead to incorrect code is irrelevant right now.

Deferring this check causes some "infinitely-typed values" to be allowed, roughly. Dynamic languages such as Python or Scheme further defer these type errors until run-time, and of course will handle self-application just fine.