# How to create a pointer in the lambda capture list?

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, initialization, c++14

How can we create a pointer in a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) lambda capture list? For example, we can create an integer variable and make the lambda stateful:

```cpp
auto lambda1 = [a = int{ 5 }]() mutable {
    a = 3;
}
```

However, when we change a to a pointer, the compiler doesn't work:

```cpp
auto lambda2 = [a = void* { nullptr }]() mutable {
    a = ...;
}
```

Another workaround is to declare a pointer outside and then copy it, but this seems very redundant

```
void* a;
auto lambda3 = [a]() mutable {
    a = ...
}
```

Comment: `a=void*{nullptr}` -> `a=(void*)nullptr` although I really question if you need this or not.  What are you doing with the pointer?

Answer (score 3):

You can `static_cast` the `nullptr` to `void*`

```
auto lambda2 = [a = static_cast<void*>(nullptr)]() mutable {
    // ..
};
```

That being said, it looks like you want to capture a pointer to some arbitrary types to the lambda. Shouldn't it be done by using templates? Maybe you want to have a look into the [generic lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233547/how-does-generic-lambda-work-in-c14) or [template parameter lists in lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

---

Thanks to *@HolyBlackCat* for pointing out for the fact, that the `std::nullptr_t` will not work for the case

```
int x; 
std::nullptr_t p = &x;// error: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int *' to 'nullptr'
```

Therefore it can not be used for this case.

You can use the std::nullptr_t as follows

```
#include <cstddef> // std::nullptr_t

auto lambda2 = [a = std::nullptr_t{}]() mutable {
    // ...
};
```

> `std::nullptr_t` is the type of the null pointer literal, `nullptr`. It is a distinct type that is not itself a pointer type or a pointer to member type. Its values are null pointer constants (see `NULL`), and **may be implicitly converted to any pointer and pointer to member type.**

Comment: Using `std::nullptr_t` makes this useless, since such pointer can't be changed to actually point to something. Your first two examples are equivalent to `a = nullptr`. Only the third snippet `a = static_cast<void*>(nullptr)` could be useful.

Comment: `int x; std::nullptr_t p = &x;` doesn't compile. `int x; void *p = &x;` does.