# Difference between Generic Lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I'm currently learning about generic lambda functions, and I am quite curious about the differences between:

`[](auto x){};`  and `[]<typename T>(T x){};`

They both do the same thing but is one faster than the other? What's the point of having these 2 syntaxes.

Comment: afaik they're equivalent. Also see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233547/how-does-generic-lambda-work-in-c14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the two are functionally equivalent, they are the features of C++14 and C++20, namely generic lambda and *template* syntax for generic lambdas, which means that the latter is *only* well-formed in C++20.

Compared to the `auto` which can accept *any* type, the latter can make lambda accept a specific type, for example:

```
[]<class T>(const std::vector<T>& x){};
```

In addition, it also enables lambda to forward parameters in a more natural form:

```
[]<class... Args>(Args&&... args) {
  return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};
```

You can get more details through the original paper [P0428](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0428r2.pdf).